# Cannot inject my own objects in Startup constructor in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I'm trying to inject my own classes using dependency injection, like this:

```
// Startup.cs
public class Startup
{
    private readonly ILogger _log;
    private readonly IMainController _controller;
    public Startup(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IMainController controller)
    {
        _log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Logger");
        _controller = controller;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IMainController, MainController>();
        // services.AddTransient<MainController, MainController>();
    }
```

and then MainController, the object to be injected

```
// MainController.cs
public interface IMainController
{
    Task Run(HttpContext context);
}
public class MainController : IMainController
{
    private readonly ILogger _log;

    public MainController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Logger");
    }
```

At runtime, I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to
>   resolve service for type 'mtss.ws.IMainController' while attempting to
>   activate 'mtss.ws.Startup'.    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)

I want to inject an ILoggerFactory in MainController (as it's doing in Startup) and then inject a newly created MainController in Startup...

Comment: What type of project are you creating? ASP.Net, Console...

Comment: It's an "ASP.NET Core Empty" project created with the "dotnet new web" command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to documentation, you should note the following

> [**Services Available in Startup**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup#services-available-in-startup)
>
> ASP.NET Core dependency injection provides services during an
>   application's startup. You can request these services by including the
>   appropriate interface as a parameter on your Startup class's
>   constructor or its Configure method. The `ConfigureServices` method
>   only takes an `IServiceCollection` parameter (but any registered
>   service can be retrieved from this collection, so additional
>   parameters are not necessary).
>
> Below are some of the services typically requested by `Startup` methods:
>
> - In the constructor: `IHostingEnvironment`, `ILogger<Startup>`
> - In the `ConfigureServices` method: `IServiceCollection`
> - In the `Configure` method: `IApplicationBuilder`, `IHostingEnvironment`,
>     `ILoggerFactory`
>
> Any services added by the `WebHostBuilder` `ConfigureServices` method may
>   be requested by the `Startup` class constructor or its `Configure` method.
>   Use `WebHostBuilder` to provide any services you need during `Startup`
>   methods.

You are trying to resolve a service that is not available when the constructor of `Startup` is called. `IMainController` is not registered as yet when the constructor is called. however, It should be available by the time `Configure` is called, allowing an opportunity to inject your custom service because it is called after `ConfigureServices` and as of RTM, a scoped service provider will be created for the `Configure` method.

```
// Startup.cs
public class Startup {
    private ILogger _log;
    private IMainController _controller;

    public Startup() {

    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddScoped<IMainController, MainController>();
        // services.AddTransient<MainController, MainController>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
               ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IMainController controller) {
        _log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Logger");
        _controller = controller;
        //...other code removed for brevity
    }
}
```

The above should work in .net-core 2.0

Comment: Great answer, another option it to define dependencies in the ConfigureServices method of WebHostBuilder (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46015231/47633)

Comment: @opensas that is correct as stated in the quote from documentation. Was unaware of how you were applying startup so went with the most likely option that was learned from Core 1.*

Answer (score 10):

Besides @nkosi answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46013224/47633, you can also add dependencies using the WebHostBuilder ConfigureServices method, like stated in the docs:

> Any services added by the WebHostBuilder ConfigureServices method may
>   be requested by the Startup class constructor or its Configure method.
>   Use WebHostBuilder to provide any services you need during Startup
>   methods.

It would be something like this

```
// ...other code removed for brevity
// in Program.cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
            services.AddScoped<IMainController, MainController>()
        )
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

and then in Startup.cs I can do the following

```
private readonly ILogger _log;
private readonly IMainController _controller;

public Startup(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IMainController controller)
{
    _log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Logger");
    _controller = controller;
}
```

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/GuardRex/f40f1b1414e175a6514f) helped me figure it out, it's got lot's of useful examples

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is impossible. The constructor of `Startup` will run before your `ConfigureServices` method, which means you are trying to inject `IMainController` **before** you register it for dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen. Are you saying it **is** possible to register a service in `Startup.ConfigureServices` and receive an instance of it in the `Startup` constructor? I'm not sure which part of my answer is wrong here, unless it's now possible to call an instance method before a constructor runs.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are building an ASP.Net Core2.0 MVC Application (but your MainController does not inherit from Controller so I am suspicious about this)  You do not need to register your controller in the DI container. The Constructor you have should be sufficient for ASP.Net to inject the ILogger concrete instance for you.

> public MainController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)

If you wanted to also add your own service into the controller, the controllers constructor would change to be thus:-

**Controller**

```
public MainController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IMyService myService)
```

Your service registration in Startup.cs may look like this:-

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
}
```

**MyService**

```
public interface IMyService
{
    void DoSomethingPLEASE();
}
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public void DoSomethingPLEASE()
    {
        // Do Something PLEASE, ANYTHING!
    }
}
```

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IMyService myServce)
    {
        myServce.DoSomethingPLEASE();
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```